# Shape made with CSS keeps overflowing parent container

Tags: html, css

I am making a little page and I need to have 2 shapes in the background (screenshot of design attached). I have made them purely with CSS. I've tried both ::before/::after for parent container, and just separate DIV-s in HTML. The problem is that in both cases the bottom right shape always keeps going out of container and the scroll appears. I thought overflow will help, but it didn't do it for me. Could anyone help me fix this?
Thank you!

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1.5rem 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.background-one {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -50%;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, $violet, $magenta);
  width: 375px;
  height: 54%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.background-two {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -50%;
  background: hsl(236, 72%, 63%);
  width: 375px;
  height: 54%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="background-one"></div>
  <div class="background-two"></div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="phone"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

[image: What I am trying to achieve without anything overflowing]

[image: What happens]

Comment: I don't have your images to test with, but I suspect your container has no height, and therefore the image is just sort of doing its best, but by default, it aligns top left. in other words the box model is breaking down. try altering the css display property on the elements.

Comment: I didn't use any images. I've just built the shapes by making a div(or ::after element) and giving it width, height and background colour. I've tried adding height, makes no difference. The problem only appears when I try to absolutely position these element to absolutely positioned parent. And this happend only on the right side. Moreover, I also start getting whitespace in the bottom for some reason, even though nothing is in there.

Comment: Ah, I see. https://jsfiddle.net/FirePrism/1fjp92rv/ That's pretty darn close to what you want, but the issue is that it's not a fluid design. It uses set values for objects (though maybe you could just swap those with proportional values). It basically would only work with a small viewport.

Comment: Well now I have finally found a way to fix it. Works fine for now. I wrote the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, finally I think I have found a solution, in case anyone will encounter the same issue. I have nested those DIVs(which are background shapes) into another DIV. I've made that container DIV cover full screen, and then positioned those shape DIVs absolutely to new container, setting the overflow for the container to hidden.

```
.newContainer {
  position: absolute;  //Its container is set to relative.
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.backgroundShape {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -50%;
  //other properties with width, height etc.
}
```